# Webkit css working in safari but not in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

Why this part of my css is working fine in safari. It fades right but when I test it in chrome it doesnt work at all. Can somebody help me how to fixed it thanks.

```
.sort-animate {
transition: all 0.5s ease;

-webkit-transition: 450ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 1.000, 1.000) all;
-moz-transition: 450ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 1.000, 1.000) all;
-ms-transition: 450ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 1.000, 1.000) all;
-o-transition: 450ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 1.000, 1.000) all;
transition: 450ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 1.000, 1.000) all;
position: relative;
display: block;
```

}

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What he said. Your problem is not reproducible with what info you've given us; it works fine in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uuujd0zw/2/).